# React: How to prevent menu component from being remounted when switching pages

Tags: reactjs

Let's say that we have a React app with two pages A and B using a shared menu component Menu.
Our app renders either page A or page B, like the example below:

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("The menu remounted");  
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="menu" className="has-scrollbar">
      <button onClick={() => props.onClick('a')}>A</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.onClick('b')}>B</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const PageA = (props) => {
  const .. = useSomeHooksUsedByPageA();
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu {...somePropsFromPageA} />
      <div>Content of page A</div>
    </div>
  );
}
  
const PageB = (props) => (
  const .. = useSomeHooksUsedByPageB();
  <div>
    <Menu {...somePropsFromPageB} />
    <div>Content of page B</div>
  </div>
  );

const App = () => {
    const [pageKey, setPageKey] = React.useState("a");
  
  switch (pageKey)
  {
     case "a":
         return <PageA key="1" onClick={setPageKey} />;
     case "b":
       return <PageB key="1" onClick={setPageKey} />;
  }
  return "true"
}
```

Now, every time we switch pages (from A to B, or B to A), the menu is remounted and a message is printed to the console.

Using this component hierarchy where the menu receives props from the page, is there any way to tell React not to remount the menu when we switch pages?

(A typical use-case could be that the menu has a scroll, and we want to keep the scroll position when navigating different pages.)

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

One potential solution for this problem is to move `<Menu/>` into the `<App/>` component, and render each page after the menu.
This provides a couple of benefits:

- The `Menu` won't be re-rendered whenever the page changes.
- The `onClick` function does not need to be passed through props on each page just to provide it to the `<Menu/>` component nested within.

[image: Edit PageMenu]

```js
const Menu = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("The menu remounted");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="menu" className="has-scrollbar">
      <button onClick={() => props.onClick("a")}>A</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.onClick("b")}>B</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const PageA = () => (
  <div>
    <div>Content of page A</div>
  </div>
);

const PageB = () => (
  <div>
    <div>Content of page B</div>
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  const [pageKey, setPageKey] = React.useState("a");

  let page;
  switch (pageKey) {
    case "b":
      page = <PageB key="2" />;
      break;
    default:
      page = <PageA key="3" />;
      break;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Menu onClick={setPageKey} />
      {page}
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

#### Edit

Further to @glingt's comment regarding the hierarchy and how this needs to function, Context might be a good candidate for the use case. If pages need to update the `<Menu/>` component's props, then using context to manage state between the menu and pages might be a better solution in terms of architecture. Instead of rendering many `<Menu/>` components inside of each child, only one `<Menu/>` can be rendered higher up in the tree. This results in the component mounting once rather than many times with each child. Effectively, context manages the state of the menu, and provides methods to update state to any children under the provider. In this case, both child pages and the menu can update and respond to state updates.

[image: Edit ContextPagePOC]

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useContext, useMemo, useState } from "react";

// Create an instance of context so we are able to update the menu from lower in the tree
const menuContext = React.createContext({});

// Add state to the context provider. Wrap props earlier in the tree with this component.
const MenuContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [pageKey, setPageKey] = useState("a");
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ pageKey, setPageKey }), [pageKey]);

  return <menuContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</menuContext.Provider>;
};

// The menu component which will:
// 1. Update the menuContext when the user selects a new pageKey
// 2. Respond to updates made to the pageKey by other components (in this case pages)
const Menu = () => {
  const { pageKey, setPageKey } = useContext(menuContext);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("The menu remounted");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="menu" className="has-scrollbar">
      <button
        onClick={() => setPageKey("a")}
        style={{ color: pageKey === "a" ? "blue" : "red" }}
      >
        A
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => setPageKey("b")}
        style={{ color: pageKey === "b" ? "blue" : "red" }}
      >
        B
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// In each page, we are able to update a value that is consumed by the menu using setPageKey
const PageA = () => {
  const { setPageKey } = useContext(menuContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Content of page A</div>
      <button onClick={() => setPageKey("b")}>Go to page B</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const PageB = () => {
  const { setPageKey } = useContext(menuContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Content of page B</div>
      <button onClick={() => setPageKey("a")}>Go to page A</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const PageComponent = () => {
  const { pageKey } = useContext(menuContext);
  switch (pageKey) {
    case "b":
      return <PageB key="2" />;
    default:
      return <PageA key="1" />;
  }
};

const App = () => (
  <MenuContext>
    <Menu />
    <PageComponent />
  </MenuContext>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but  as stated in the question formulation I need to keep the component structure. In my case, I want to use hooks in PageA and PageB and pass the results down to the menu component.

Comment: My apologies, I failed to read that part of your question. I'll work on another solution based on that requirement :)

Comment: Would something like passing the menu into each page as a prop work in your case?  I have a solution that would also work, but it requires passing a menu prop into each page in some capacity. For example:  `<PageA key="1" menu={menu}/>`

Comment: Each page might use its own hooks and pass the result to the menu as props. Therefore, <Menu /> must be returned from within the Pages. This is what I mean with ”keeping the component hierarchy”. I was a bit unclear here, should make that clearer in my post.

Comment: @glingt I've updated my answer based on your comment. From what I gather you're looking for a way for the child components to be able to update the state of the menu without having the menu be rendered anew on each child component render. I think a good solution could be found in react context: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: I appreciate your efforts trying to find a workaround to the problem. But as stated in the question, the component hierarchy page->menu is a requirement. There are multiple reasons for this, but I wanted to leave all those details out to make the question brief and simple. One of the reasons why we need the hierarchy page->menu is that we want the menu DOM elements to be children of the page, for layout reasons. We need the menu to be rendered inside the page dom, not the opposite.

Comment: I see, since the Menu is being rendered within each child, it will be mounted and unmounted with its parent component. I tried a few ways to use the exact same component in both children, but wasn't able to achieve the desired goal of only one mount. You mentioned in your question that one of the reasons you need to prevent the menu from mounting with each page is due to scroll position. Is it possible you could use something like redux or context to store any values that need to persist between components and load it in as a menu prop each time a new page is selected?